# Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]

Tags: android, flutter, adb

I'm using last version of flutter and dart.
First I installed my app from play store and after that I've attached my device(Samsung S8+ with android 9) for debugging, it's shown me this error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]
```

After some searches I've done theses works:

> - uninstall from all user the currently installed copy
> - adb uninstall "Package name"
> - downgrade android:version from manifest.xml

and they haven't worked!
I realized my app version from app manager and I would edit version:
`version: 3.8.0+62` -> `version: 3.11.0+66`
from `pubspec.yaml`, it's shown me this:

```
signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!
```

I think the previous apk is already installed but it doesn't exist in system App manager.

Other projects working fine.

What should I do?

Comment: You said you downloaded from playstore, then what does `attached my device(Samsung S8+ with android 9) for debugging` mean? Isn't that the device you  used to install the app?

Comment: Sorry about my bad words, first I've already had it from playstore then I would try using it in debug mode. No it's the same. @10101010

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by ` try using it in debug mode`. What did you do to make it run in debug mode? Running your code would install the debug version of app which might conflict with the play store app.

Comment: So, what should I do for this conflict? @10101010

Comment: Don't have your release app when you are trying to run your project code.

Comment: This message `signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!` is a warning, if you wait it out the app should install properly on your device.

Comment: Yes, I have @10101010

Comment: No, it's not. It was the main message I told. It said ADB exit with code 1, Perform error or something like this. @AliAmin

Comment: I have seen this error: `signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!` when trying to install an app with same version number and package name built on a different computer than the previously installed one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the below steps did it for me. Hopefully this will help others.

---

### Possible Solution

On the terminal, run following commands (ensuring adb is on `$PATH`):

```
$ adb uninstall [package_name]
```

`[package_name]` here would be in the form `com.domain.appname`.

```
$ adb install -r -d [path_to_debug_apk]
```

`-d` allows version downgrade for debug builds.

`-r` is to replace existing application and may be redundant if the uninstall succeeded in completely purging previous installed copy. I was just a bit paranoid and used it.

See `$ adb help` for more details.

It is then possible to attach to this debug build from terminal using `flutter attach`, and get the debug log on terminal just like `flutter run`.

I believe now that it should be possible to execute `flutter run` too after the first uninstall step without errors.

---

#### The error message and some back-story

I had a similar problem with `flutter run` while trying to debug an app while I had a release version of it installed on the device already.

I got an adb error stating:

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /path_to_project/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk: 
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]

Error launching application on [deviceName]
```

Like in your case, uninstalling the app from application manager on the phone did not remove this error.

Comment: I have the same problem. This work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Error (Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE])
I just clear the cache(Application manager) and uninstall the app then Build it again and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this problem and using physical device for development, problem is probably caused because you installed a version that you build and remove it later.

Solution is simple, for my case, I just installed another build of my app and then go back to android studio and ran the flutter, again synced all the data, and I continued to develop.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
adb shell pm uninstall "packagename"
```

and then install the app using adb or

```
flutter install
```