# uninstall app fully still appears the error INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE when I install my app

Tags: android, flutter, apk

background:

```
1. I have installed the APK  with the 1.1.30 version built by flutter.
2. I want to install it back to 1.1.29
3. I uninstall the 1.1.30 app.
4. I install the 1.1.29 package, and it will throw the error package appears to be invalid.
5. I try to use ADB to install it, but the error will change to  INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE: Package Verification Result
6. no idea why the app built by flutter will cause this issue, even if I uninstall the app fully.
7. the solution is using ADB install -r -d [path_to_debug_apk] to replace and downgrade the app.
```

can someone explain why this happened? is the app can not uninstall completely? thanks.

also refer to this link: [Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134157/error-adb-exited-with-exit-code-1-failure-install-failed-version-downgrade)

it seems the same to me who still can not install it even though the app was removed.

---

some information added:
I used adb shell cmd package list packages, can not find my app but the command with adb shell dumpsys package[pageckage name] can find my app.
so weird

---

Comment: Pretty sure it means you did not uninstall the app. Maybe you just removed it from your home screen.

Comment: no I am sure I have removed the app. since I have used = adb shell pm list packages= to check my app, it is gone.

Comment: Do you have multiple profiles? e.g. a work profile? or another user for which the app is still installed?

Comment: @Pierre thank you! I ended up on this SO and uninstalling app from work profile resolved the issue.